# Using and saving custom dropdown boxes on user profiles

Tags: php, plugin-development

Okay, so I'm creating a website and am in need of help for some custom meta fields for user profiles. Currently I have the following in my functions.php file:

```
//hooks
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );

function Add_user_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3 class="sizeShapeH3">Select Chapters</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">MPF Chapters </label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_top" id="user_top">
                <option value="MPF Pune Central:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune Central:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune Central:</option>
                <option value="MPF Pune East:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune East:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune East:</option>
                <option value="MPF Pune West:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune West:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune West:</option>
                <option value="MPF Pune South:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF Pune South:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune South:</option>
                <option value="MPF PCMC:" <?php echo ($topselected == "MPF PCMC:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF PCMC:</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );

function save_user_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    //save top
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_chapters', $_POST['user_chapters'] );

}
```

All of the code seems to work and when I click "Update Profile" it works (I think), but the drop-downs display the first item, instead of the selected item by the user. So if a user selected "Yoga Top" and clicked on "Save", "I Got Guns" is displayed instead of "Yoga Top", which the user selected. Is there anyway I can fix this?

I would really appreciate any help as we are under the gun in terms of time.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the data in the `$selected` value, while using `$topselected` in the conditionals to check which value is selected.

Either change your value like this:

```
$topselected= get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID );
```

**OR** change your inline conditionals to this:

```
<option value="MPF Pune West:" <?php echo ($selected== "MPF Pune West:")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>MPF Pune West:</option>
```

### UPDATE

Based on @birgire's comments, you can use the built in `selected()` function:

```
<select name="user_top" id="user_top">
    <option value="MPF Pune Central:" <?php selected( $selected , "MPF Pune Central:" ); ?>>MPF Pune Central:</option>
    <option value="MPF Pune East:" <?php selected( $selected , "MPF Pune East:" ); ?>>MPF Pune East:</option>
    <option value="MPF Pune West:" <?php selected( $selected , "MPF Pune West:" ); ?>>MPF Pune West:</option>
    <option value="MPF Pune South:" <?php selected( $selected , "MPF Pune South:" ); ?>>MPF Pune South:</option>
    <option value="MPF PCMC:" <?php selected( $selected , "MPF PCMC:" ); ?>>MPF PCMC:</option>
</select>
```

Comment: WordPress has it's own [`selected()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/) helper function

Comment: dont working what should i do.?

Comment: Birgir, I should have you installed on my computer as codex :) @birgire

Comment: dont working your update code

Comment: @AnilPatidar Are you sure `get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID ); ` is returning anything? You might not be saving the data at the first place.

Comment: do not work gyessss